# How can I find repeated words and separate from sentences?

Tags: swift, xcode

For example. I have string value like this :

```
var str = "asdImverygreatfullasdandeverythingwillbegoodandIwillbehappy"
```

there is 'asd' and 'and' these two words repeat between sentences. I want to find these two words and remove from str. Is that possible?

Desire output will be :

```
str = "ImverygreatfulleverythingwillbegoodIwillbehappy"
```

Comment: What is going to happen with the `and` before `every`?

Comment: Can you please Show me your desire output?

Comment: sorry, I edited my desire output @NamraParmar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An efficient way is to replace the substrings with help of  Regular Expression

```
let str = "asdImverygreatfullasdandeverythingwillbegoodandIwillbehappy"
let cleaned = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "a(s|n)d", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
```

`"a(s|n)d"` means find both `"asd"` and `"and"`

Comment: Thaks for your answer@vadian

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this : -

```
     var str = "asdImverygreatfullasdandeverythingwillbegoodandIwillbehappy"
     str = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "asd", with: "")
     str = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "and", with: "")
     print("Answer : - \(str)")
```

Your Answer will be

```
     Answer : - ImverygreatfulleverythingwillbegoodIwillbehappy
```

Comment: @yasin89, yes from above code you can find anything and replace that with output you desire from the string even if you are not able to see the entire string. Just for information, If you just want to see that if string contain what you need then you can use String.contain("asd"), this will give you Bool value.